Different wire length on secondary of a transformer, is this detrimental?
So I’m in the neon industry, and the manufacturers of solid state switched mode HV power supplies recommend using the same length of wire for both ends of the secondary, which would require putting the supply in the middle of your 30 feet of neon (neon units run in series, up to 48 feet at 15kV) as opposed to putting it at the start and running 30 feet of secondary wiring to the other end. Likewise, some in the industry even say the same should be done when using an iron core transformer. Is there any truth to this, if so, please explain. Thanks!

Why would the supplier lie to you about this. Please justify why you think the supplier is telling you lies. I mean, it's not in their interest to make up arbitrary restrictions on the use of a piece of equipment that they sell is it? More the opposite I would say.

Is it really a matter of wire length, or is their recommendation resulting in parallel connection of two 15ft strings?

Equal lengths are best for good balance, equal capacitance to ground. The higher the frequency the more important this is. I have not seen this on old 50 Hz 5 kV stuff. Balance is good for EMC.
